# Paramiko sftp.get append date to saved file

Tags: python

I'm trying to use Paramiko to pull a file from a remote node, and save it locally with the month, date, and year appended to the saved file.

This is what I've come up with so far, but at a bit of a loss on how to pull this off.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import paramiko
import os
import datetime
import sys

# variables defined here, should probably reference an external file instead, hardcoded for now
switch_ip = '10.175.2.17'  
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
datestamp = datetime.datetime.now()

try:
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())    
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())    
    client.connect(switch_ip, username=username, password=password)

    sftp = client.open_sftp()
    sftp.get('primary.cfg', '/backups/nodes/DC1/primary.cfg' + '.' (datestamp.strftime("%m%d%y")))

finally:
    client.close()
```

Comment: What is the problem? Please explain.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit vague, but when I run this script this is the output I receive: 

`$ ./myscript.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myscript.py", line 29, in <module>
    sftp.get('primary.cfg', '/backups/nodes/DC1/primary.cfg' + '.' (datestamp.strftime("%m%d%y")))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

What I'm trying to do is pull "primary.cfg" from my remote node (this portion works), but save the downloaded file locally with the date appended such as "primary.cfg.062019" in the dircetory specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot a plus operator (+)

change

```
sftp.get('primary.cfg', '/backups/nodes/DC1/primary.cfg' + '.' (datestamp.strftime("%m%d%y")))
```

to

```
sftp.get('primary.cfg', '/backups/nodes/DC1/primary.cfg' + '.'  + (datestamp.strftime("%m%d%y")))
```

Comment: This did it, thank you! This makes sense and was such a simple mistake that I overlooked, it is working as expected now :)